# How to set login button of custom IdP on azure b2c

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to add my custom IDP integration to my B2C login and I am having trouble in the first step, to put a custom login button on the login page.

I did the same thing with google with success but could not did this with my custom IDP. The only button that appears is google. Any idea on how to add the login button of my custom IDP?

[image]

Here's my policy:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
  
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MyCustomExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="MyCustomExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    ...
  </UserJourney>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Had to set DisplayName on the Technical Profile

```
    <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="MyCustom-OAuth2">
        <DisplayName>MyCustom Button</DisplayName>
        ...
    </TechnicalProfiles>
```

Here's the journey:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
  
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="MyCustomExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="MyCustomExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="MyCustom-OAuth2" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    ...
```